# How can I auto serialize/deserialize case classes with traits using Json play

Tags: scala, play-json

I have a case class with a bunch of fields, two of them are `trait` and have children classes. Something like this:

```scala
trait Trait1
case class T11(a: String) extends Trait1
case class T12(b: Int, c: Double) extends Trait1

trait Trait2
case class T21(a: Int, b: Int) extends Trait2
case class T22(a: Double, b: String, c: Boolean) extends Trait2

case class F1(...)
case class F2(...)

case class CaseClass(field1: F1, field2: F2, field3: Option[Trait1] = None, field4: Option[Trait2] = None)
```

For backward compatibility, I need to make sure the content of `Trait1` and `Trait2` are serialized to json at the top level of my class `CaseClass`. i.e. something like this

```json
{
  "field1": {...},
  "field2": {...},
  "a1": ...,
  "a2": ...,
  "b2": ...
}
```

I tried with the following logic to serialize and deserialize my class `CaseClass` as well as the other traits and their children classes

```scala
object Trait1 {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Trait1] = {
    implicit def format1: OFormat[T11] = Json.format[T11]
    implicit def format2: OFormat[T12] = Json.format[T12]
    Json.format[Trait1]
  }
}
object Trait2 {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Trait2] = {
    implicit def format1: OFormat[T21] = Json.format[T21]
    implicit def format2: OFormat[T22] = Json.format[T22]
    Json.format[Trait2]
  }
}
object T21 {
  implicit val format = Json.format[T21]
}
object T22 {
  implicit val format = Json.format[T22]
}
object CaseClass {
  implicit val reads: Reads[CaseClass] = (JsPath \ "field1").read[F1]
  .and((JsPath \ "field2").read[F2])
      .and(JsPath.readNullable[Trait1])
      .and(JsPath.readNullable[Trait2])
  .apply(CaseClass.apply _)

  implicit val writes: Writes[CaseClass] =
    (JsPath \ "field1").write[F1]
      .and((JsPath \ "field2").write[F2])
      .and(JsPath.writeNullable[Trait1])
      .and(JsPath.writeNullable[Trait2])
      .apply(unlift(CaseClass.unapply))
}
```

With this logic I can serialize the class into the target json as wanted with `Json.toJson`, but i tried to deseriliaze that Json back to classes with `Json.parse` it fails with something like this

```
JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.invalid),WrappedArray())))))
play.api.libs.json.JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.invalid),WrappedArray())))))
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.$anonfun$as$2(JsReadable.scala:25)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsError.fold(JsResult.scala:64)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.as(JsReadable.scala:24)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsReadable.as$(JsReadable.scala:23)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsObject.as(JsValue.scala:124)
    at dzlab.CaseClassTest.jsonReadComparison(CaseClassTest.scala:45)
```

Comment: I don't think you can `Read` a trait "magically": you'll have to implement a read logic that tries each subclass or use a discriminant.

Comment: yeahI'm planning to deserialize manually but was wondering if there could be an alternative

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#requirements), you can see that macro generated handlers support sealed traits.